# How to send message to multiple users using sms manger in Android Studio?

Tags: java

I'd like to send a message to multiple users using the SMS manager.

In my project, there is one form, which has name, phone number, email id and message fields. In this case, when I click the **submit** button, the message should be sent to the client (who is filling the form) and the admin.

I am receiving it in both client and admin side. But I am only getting one duplicate message in client side. The duplicate message means what it was sent to the admin side that same copy coming to the client side.

Following is my code base:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String name;
String phone;
String email;
String mess;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String phone = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone)).getText().toString();
            String email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
            String mess = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage)).getText().toString();
            String number = "9791083064";
            String receipentsNumber[] = {phone,number};




            Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            mail.setType("message/rfc822");
            mail.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:sudhanmanoharan@gmail.com"));
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Name: " + name + "\nPhone Number: " + phone + "\nEmail: " + email + "\nMessage: " + mess);
            mail.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(mail);

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i <= receipentsNumber.length; i++) {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(receipentsNumber[i], null, "Name: " + name + "\nPhone Number: " + phone + "\nEmail: " + email + "\nMessage: " + mess, null, null);
                }                    //smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, "Name: " + name + "\nPhone Number: " + phone + "\nEmail: " + email + "\nMessage: " + mess, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


}
```